# Web App with slow emails delivery

Tags: web, smtp, office365

I have a web app that sends emails to my clients, like reminders and Im sending it with authentication, but it is too slow (Office 365 SMTP).

I want to know if there is some tip to use Office 365 SMTP or I have to use another SMTP service.

This is my code to send my emails:

```
sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
Set cdoConfig = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
cdoConfig.Fields.Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2
cdoConfig.Fields.Item(sch & "smtpauthenticate") = 1
cdoConfig.Fields.Item(sch & "smtpserver") = MAIL_HOST
cdoConfig.Fields.Item(sch & "smtpserverport") = 25
cdoConfig.Fields.Item(sch & "smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30
cdoConfig.Fields.Item(sch & "sendusername") = MAIL_USERNAME
cdoConfig.Fields.Item(sch & "sendpassword") = MAIL_PASSWORD
cdoConfig.Fields.Item(sch & "smtpusessl") = true

cdoConfig.fields.update
Set cdoMessage = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set cdoMessage.Configuration = cdoConfig
Set cdoConfig = Nothing

cdoMessage.BodyPart.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
cdoMessage.From = MAIL_FROM & "<" & MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS & ">"
cdoMessage.To = MAIL_TO & "<" & MAIL_TO_ADDRESS & ">"
cdoMessage.Subject = MAIL_SUBJECT

cdoMessage.HTMLBody = MAIL_BODY

cdoMessage.Send

Set cdoMessage = Nothing
```

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a code example of what you have right now, or take a look at this post: [Sending mail using smtp is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182626/sending-mail-using-smtp-is-too-slow)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a well documented issue w/ smtp.office365.com.

I too am fighting to have them fix it on their end along with others.

Here is an excellent example thread:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/74410bfb-c2d5-460a-9bb7-2da6e1aa97a0/imap-smtp-slow-performance-on-office-365-10sec-idle-time-before-receivingsending-data?forum=officeitpro

search for "smtp.office365.com slow to send" for other examples.

I would suggest getting on the phone / email with office365.com (microsoft) and complain to help get this resolved.  It's likely a tarpit or similar setup by them to prevent hacking attempts or to just 'encourage' people to use their product (Office) which in our use cases is impossible.